# android app connect to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, android, image

I have no idea of php but the code should be something like this
    `

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $user_pass, $db_name);


if($con)
{
$image = $_POST ["image"];
$name = $_POST ["name"];
$sql = "insert into imageinfo(name) values('$name')";
$upload_path = "uploads/$name.jpg";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
file_put_contents($upload_path,base64_decode($image));
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image Upload Successfully'));
}
else
{
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image upload failed1'));
}
}
else
{
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image Upload Failed2'));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>`
```

I'm getting an error of unidentified objets image and name from `($image = $_POST ["image"]..)`. If I use `if(isset)` I get the below response:

> Image upload failed2

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space

```
$image = $_POST["image"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are not sending the "image" and "name" from the api request thats why it is not set.

Comment: I actually get uploading successful from POSTMAN of a image, but without a name.

Answer (score 0):

You got "Image upload failed2" response when your database connection is failed.

Please check your connection by adding below code:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Your code looks something like:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $user_pass, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if ($con)
{
    $image = $_POST ["image"];
    $name = $_POST ["name"];
    $sql = "insert into imageinfo(name) values('$name')";
    $upload_path = "uploads/$name.jpg";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        file_put_contents($upload_path, base64_decode($image));
        echo json_encode(array('response' => 'Image Upload Successfully'));
    } else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('response' => 'Image upload failed1'));
    }
} else
{
    echo json_encode(array('response' => 'Image Upload Failed2'));
}
mysqli_close($con);
```